# How to visualize a series of time differences?

Tags: plotting, visualization, date-and-time

> Question: Given a series of times how can we visualize the time between dates?

**Context**

I have data of the following structure:

```
{{"2018-07-31 21:32:52", "2018-07-31 22:12:27", 
  Quantity[0.0274884, "Days"]}, {"2018-08-02 19:11:59", 
  "2018-08-02 19:12:40", 
  Quantity[0.000474537, "Days"]}, {"2018-08-02 19:12:40", 
  "2018-08-07 20:35:19", 
  Quantity[5.0574, "Days"]}, {"2018-08-07 20:36:05", 
  "2018-08-07 20:36:05", Quantity[0, "Days"]}, {"2018-08-07 20:36:46",
   "2018-08-07 20:36:46", 
  Quantity[0, "Days"]}, {"2018-08-08 18:46:26", "2018-08-08 18:46:54",
   Quantity[0.000324074, "Days"]}, {"2018-08-08 18:46:54", 
  "2018-08-08 18:47:34", 
  Quantity[0.000462963, "Days"]}, {"2018-08-08 18:47:34", 
  "2018-08-08 18:54:15", 
  Quantity[0.0046412, "Days"]}, {"2018-08-08 18:54:49", 
  "2018-08-08 18:54:49", Quantity[0, "Days"]}, {"2018-08-08 18:55:55",
   "2018-08-08 18:55:55", Quantity[0, "Days"]}}
```

A list containing a list of two dates as the first element and their difference, as the second element. This data is derived from user interactions to a series of questions and we want to know how long it took to respond in minutes.

**What I've Tried**

So, I have tried to create a `Grid` to display the data where every two rows, we display the difference. However, this doesn't have an immediate visual effect that a graph might.

I have also considered using `TimelinePlot` which has an "Interval" capability. I did the following:

```
TimelinePlot[DateObject[#]& /@ listOfDates]
```

which produces something somewhat meaningful (see graphic) but some dates are vertically stacked where, I think, everything horizontal would be better.

[image: Sample timeline plot]

Comment: Aren't you just looking for a histogram of user response times ?  Or even a simple scatter plot ?  I'm not sure this is a programming question, it seems more like a data visualisation design question.

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation of the data structure. What I see here is just a list of dates. I don't see a list of lists and I don't see any differences.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, I've updated the question to include a new data structure which includes dates and their time differences.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark A histogram / scatter plot won't do because I would like something like a timeline except the points shouldn't be stacked.

Comment: The list in your answer is not valid Mathematica code someone can copy and paste in a notebook. Can you include the definition of `listOfDates` (or at least: a definition of the first 5 elements or so) that people can use directly? You can just evaluate `listOfDates[[;; 5]]` and paste the results in here.

Comment: I have updated the question for posterity but I've answered my own question - and I think that's what I wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use a `TimelinePlot`. I have a list of dates like:

```
listOfDates = {"2018-07-31 21:32:52", "2018-07-31 22:12:27", ...}
```

In order to visualize the times for the data, I converted each time to a `TimeObject`

```
TimeObject[#] & /@ listOfDates
```

And then plot each of them using a `TimelinePlot`. The important part was `PlotLayout -> "Stacked"`. This generates a plot where each event has it's own row. So we visualize difference by the distance between dots.

The final function is:

```
TimelinePlot[TimeObject[#] & /@ listOfDates, PlotLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

And we ultimately end up with something like:

[image: Timeline Plot]